# Matching text from corrupted filenames with stringr

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe where one column is waypoint names from GPS files. Some of the waypoints have been corrupted, and the names of these are in an odd format with symbols which (I think) are not alphanumeric.

I'm ultimately trying to remove these filenames from the data, but I'm not sure how to properly match non alphanumeric text. I've tried the below code, comparing matching text from the incorrect text format with the correctly formatted filenames.

With each one I'm getting unexpected behaviour, presumably due to incorrect syntax or possibly because some of the odd symbols are actually counted as alphanumeric characters?

How do I properly use stringr to match these corrupted filenames?

```
corrupt_names <- c("çŸ¸Ð¥ê¦‰ã €", "çµ€Ð¨î†ƒã¥ºã¸ž>Ä©","ç€Ð¥Üã£—","ç¾ˆÐ¥î„…ã¡ƒ") # create example filenames
correct_names <- c("1050M", "1800L","Newwaypoint1") # create example of correct filenames

str_view(corrupt_names,"[^alnum]+") # seems to select correct non alphanumeric symbols
str_view(correct_names,"[^alnum]+") # but this also selects alphanumeric characters in the correct names vector?

str_view(corrupt_names,"[^[:alnum:]]+") # selects only some symbols
str_view(correct_names,"[^[:alnum:]]+") # seems to work ok, doesn't select anything
```

Edit: after creating the example vectors in my r script, I receive a warning when trying to save the file: "Not all of the characters in C:/Myfile.R could be encoded using ISO8859-1. To save using a different encoding, choose "File | Save with Encoding..." from the main menu. I assume this is relevant to the issue.

Comment: `[^alnum]` is wrong, it just matches any char other than `a`, `l`, `n`, `u` and `m`. `[^[:alnum:]]+` matches one or more non-alphanumeric chars.

Comment: Right, thank you, that make sense. So with the correct syntax, it only matches a few characters as not being alphanumeric, and when matching for alphanumeric, again, only a few characters are picked up. So it seems like there's a mix of alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric and missed characters?

Comment: Well, I believe you wanted to match non-ASCII letters. Try `str_view(corrupt_names,"[^[:ascii:]]+")`

Comment: To save as file, you need to use something like `Encoding(str) <- "unknown"` and then `cat(str, file="File/path/here")`

Comment: That matches a lot of the characters now, thanks! It doesn't capture symbols like ">", and trying 'str_view(corrupt_names,"[[:punct:]]+")' doesn't seem to match them either, not sure why.

Comment: Sure, it is ICU. So, you probably want to get anything other than ASCII letters and digits? Then you need `str_view(corrupt_names,"[^A-Za-z0-9]")`. Please clarify the pattern requirements. What should it match, or - if easier (as I have just shown) - what should it not show?

Comment: Your latest example matches everything - thanks! I wasn't quite sure what exactly I needed matching as I'm not familiar with the terminology, but this has solved it. Am I able to accept your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find all entries containing any char other than ASCII letters and digits.

You can use

```r
str_view(corrupt_names,"[^A-Za-z0-9]")
```

`[^A-Za-z0-9]` presents a negated character class that matches any char other than a letter from `A-Z` and `a-z` ranges and other than a digit, `0-9`.